# Оптимизация SQL запроса выборки из большой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос касается двух таблиц с числом записей более 1 миллиона.
Таблица клиентов и таблица заказов. 
Нужно выбрать топ 250 клиентов с максимальной суммой по успешным заказам.

```
SELECT 
Sum(`O`.`total`) AS `totalsum`,
`U.`firstname` AS `name`,
`U`.`lastname` AS `surname`,
`U`.`email` AS `mail`
FROM `users` AS `U`
JOIN `orders` AS `O` ON (`U`.`id` = `O`.`userid`)
WHERE `O`.`status` = success
GROUP BY `totalsum` DESC LIMIT 250
```

Набросал на скорую, уверен что с небольшими таблицами подобным запросом можно было бы обойтись, но на таблице с 1кк+ записей думаю сервер неплохо так загрузится.

Дайте пожалуйста, совет как можно оптимизировать запрос для такой задачи.

Comment: Храните в клиентах сумму их успешных заказов, которая пересчитывается по клиенту при изменении его успешных заказов, тогда запрос будет элементарный без вычислений. И индекс на поле с суммой обязательно.

Comment: Запрос странный ... очень странный ... функция sum() выполняется после group by по условиям группировки. А вы почему то группируете по этой самой сумме ... я бы на месте СУБД выдал ошибку на такой запрос. Хотя если у вас MySQL он может ошибки и не дать, а дать просто не предсказуемый результат

Comment: Вариант, но не гибко получится, т.к. при подсчете суммы заказов скажем за последний месяц/ неделю... информация будет не актуальной.

Comment: Если суммарную информацию вести триггером на таблицу orders то сумма всегда будет актуальной

Comment: В запросе из вопроса нужно заменить слово `GROUP` на `ORDER`, а группировку по id юзера делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну запрос, вероятно, должен быть

```
SELECT Sum(`O`.`total`) AS `totalsum`,
       `U.`firstname` AS `name`,
       `U`.`lastname` AS `surname`,
       `U`.`email` AS `mail`
FROM `users` AS `U`
JOIN `orders` AS `O` ON (`U`.`id` = `O`.`userid`)
WHERE `O`.`status` = success
GROUP BY /* `U`.`id` -- если разрешены "кривые" группировки*/
         `U.`firstname`, 
         `U`.`lastname`, 
         `U`.`email`
ORDER BY `totalsum` DESC 
LIMIT 250
```

А оптимизировать можно созданием индекса orders (userid, status, total). Полагаю, что users.id - уже индекс, да ещё и первичный...